# What is the orange color symbol in the new line?

Tags: front-end, style, system

In mathematica v 13.1 ,

If I type `+` key of my keyboard in a new cell, I see

[image]

What is it? Also if I type `+` twice in a new cell, its variant is seen.

They may be features related to style, but I am not sure.

And how do I disable it ?

There is a workaround, type any letter and then type `+`, then delete the first letter.

But I just want to disable this feature directly.

+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-

`1` `2` `3` `4` `5` `6` `7` `8` `9` `0` `dash/minus` `plus/equal` `backspace`

`shift` + `plus/equal` works fine, meaning normal `+` sign appears even if it is the starting of a new cell.

+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-
There is **another** `+` key as you know.

`7` `8` `9`
`4` `5` `6` `+`
`1` `2` `3`

If I click **this** `+`, then `Free Form Input` is generated(without shift key pressed).

Comment: [`Free form input`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/FreeFormAndExternalInput.html)

Comment: Please visit:  [Free form input](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/EnterFreeFormInput.html) and [Using Wolfram Alpha inside a notebook](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/UseWolframAlphaInsideANotebook.html).

Comment: Thank you, and is it possible to disable it ? (related to `+` )

Comment: Well, I think this only appears when you type `=`? Is your Shift key broken?

Comment: My shift key is Ok, and the `+` in the NumLock area generates `Free Form Input` if it is typed in a new cell.

Comment: I didn't know that it was more basically connected to `=` key.

Comment: Thank you! kglr's answer at @Syed's link works!